# How to use an access query containing macro/module through php?

Tags: php, odbc

How to use an access query containing macro/module through php?

In Microsoft Access, i'm using a macro to export the result of my query to an excel workbook. I want to know:

- how to run the macro through sql query in Microsoft Access;
- How to run the query containing a macro/module through ODBC connection from PHP;

When I run a query containing macro/module directly in Microsoft Access, it works. But when I submit the query through PHP, it says: "Function cannot be found".

Help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Your ODBC driver does not know of the existence of your module function so you can't use it.

Edit: take it from a [Microsoft MVP](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=156420) if you don't believe me ;)

> Not that I'm aware of. Unfortunately user-created custom functions are executed via Microsoft Access and not via Jet.
>
> The only comparable alternative would be SQL Server Express and stored procedures.

Or read about it [here](http://www.dbforums.com/php/1617527-php-ms-access-vba-query.html)

> Native Access databases (JET) do not support user written functions, any user written functions are are called by the presentation layer not the database layer

Comment: So is there no way through which I can run a macro/module of access through PHP or for that instance any other language???
I seriously doubt it.

Comment: Not by issuing a query through your ODBC driver.

Comment: It seems it is possible. By disabling sandbox mode in Windows registry. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294698

Comment: When you disable sandbox mode, you can start the functions mentioned in the table "Understand Access functions and Access properties that are blocked by Jet 4.0 Sandbox mode". You cannot use VBA functions as those are executed by Access, not the JET/ODBC driver.

Comment: Yeah... you are right. So how can i use <b>soundex</b> to compare data in my database? Please suggest any alternative.

Comment: One way: have a soundex php function and save the soundex return in another column, then compare that column. Thats the only way to do it on the "database server" side with JET. One other solution would be comparing the data in PHP (to slow) or change the server to something with stored procs like MS SQL and write a soundex function for MSSQL